# stop executing javascript till full cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I made this script to fadeout and fadein (fadeTo) a div when I hover another div, it's almost working perfect but when I quickly hover in and out the div the script keeps looping until it reaches the times I hovered it.

Is it possible to stop (timeout?) the fadeOut/FadeIn effect till the loop is completed? So it stops repeating with a quick hover in and out but that the script works again when the loop is finished

**jsFiddle:** (quickly hover in and out the red part a few times, you'll notice the text keeps going)
http://jsfiddle.net/v69Jk/

```
$(function () {
$('.one').hover(function () {
    $('.show').fadeTo(600, 0);
},

function () {
    $('.show').fadeTo(600, 1);
});
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v69Jk/1/ try with this. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**: cancel the previous animation:

```
$(function () {
    $('.one').hover(function () {
        $('.show').stop().fadeTo(600, 0);
    },

    function () {
        $('.show').stop().fadeTo(600, 1);
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/B87Cv/)

**Solution 2**: stop event when the animation is not done yet (as you wanted, but this might not work properly because of the `hover` function)

```
$(function () {
    $('.one').hover(function () {
        if (!$('.show').is(':animated')) {
            $('.show').fadeTo(600, 0);
        }
    },

    function () {
        if (!$('.show').is(':animated')) {
            $('.show').fadeTo(600, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/z65pm/)

Comment: Solution 1 did the trick! Why didn't I came up with this.. thank you!